# Installed Ubuntu on new SSD, boots on my main PC but not on my laptop

Tags: ssd

I wanted to upgrade the old hdd on my laptop (samsung NP305U1A), where i was running Ubuntu with no problems at all.

I connected the new ssd (Samsung 860 EVO) and tried to install Ubuntu, but the ssd wouldn't show up in the installer (neither it let me select between "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", "Something else"...). I tried using legacy and UEFI mode, and AHCI mode was selected in BIOS. The ssd was showing up in BIOS settings, but only the first time i connected it. For example, if i connect my ssd and then i enter the BIOS, i can see it. Then i try to install Ubuntu, fail, restart the machine, enter BIOS, i no longer can see my ssd. If I disconnect my ssd, and connect it back, then if i enter the BIOS i can see it again.

I then tried to install Ubuntu from my main PC, and everything worked with no problem. I restarted the computer and i was able to log into Ubuntu.

At this point i removed the ssd from the machine and connected it back on my laptop. Again, i can see the ssd only one time, and if i try to boot into Ubuntu (from GRUB, that worked fine) i get an error saying: "Gave up waiting for root device..."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem with the laptop.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: The version i'm using is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @user68186 of what kind? like the laptop does not support ssd?

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS of the laptop? If the laptop is really really old, the BIOS may be the problem.

Comment: In addition to updateing UEFI, you may need to update firmware on SSD, even if new.